# Updating a service variable in one controller and using the updated value in another controller - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have defined a service called `NameService` in my `controller.js`. I want to use the variable present in the `NameService` in two different controllers.

My service is as follows

```
App.service('NameService', function(){
  this.Name = "";
  this.getName = function(){
    return this.Name;
  };
  this.setName = function(name){
    this.Name = name;
  }
});
```

I have a controller named `netController` in which I am updating the value of the `Name` variable present in my `Nameservice`. I want to use the updated value in my `page1Controller`.

`NetController` is as follows:

```
App.controller('netController', ['$scope','$http','$window','NameService',  function($scope,$http,$window,NameService)
    {
        $scope.initNet = function()
        {
            $http.post('/initNet',$scope.network).success(function(response) 
            {
                if(response.status == "true")
                {
                     $scope.$watch('NameService.setName()', function(){
                        NameService.Name = $scope.network.name;
                     });
                     NameService.setName($scope.network.name);
                     $window.location.href = '/page1';
                } 
                else
                {
                    $scope.error = "Error!";
                }
            });
        }
    }]);
```

If i do `console.log(NameService.netName);` in my `netController` it is printing the updated value.

`page1Controller` is as follows

```
    App.controller('page1Controller', ['$scope', '$http','NameService', function($scope, $http,NameService)
    {
          console.log(NameService.Name);
    }]);
```

When is do `console.log(NameService.name);` in my `page1Controller` it is giving empty string.

Can someone please help me in fixing this?

Comment: You have function NameService.getName() to get the name. Yet on one place you use NameService.netName to get it and on the other place you use NameService.name? Why not use NameService.getName() on both places?

Comment: I have made changes to the code! Still the same error.

Comment: @Minions When does page1Controller get instantiated in relation to netController? Because of the $http call it could just be a timing issue of when you're attemping to retrieve the value. Also, definitely use Factory instead of Service so that you can properly encapsulate the name field. Otherwise someone else can easily overwrite the value of the backing variable without even needing to use your Set() method

Comment: My answer works. Take a look at it. It updates the `Name` across controllers.

Comment: Put the watcher at the beginning of the controller outside of everything and add in a parameter to be passed the the function because you do not have one. Use my first example of using a watcher. `$scope.$watch('NameService.setName()', function (newName) {
     NameService.Name = newName
 });`

Comment: I noticed you registered your service to the *gisApp module* but then you have registered the controllers to the module *App*. Is this a typo or are you actually doing this?

Answer (score 0):

use factory instead of service

```
gisApp.factory('NameService', function () {
    var _name = "";
    return {

        getName: function () {
            return _name;
        },
        setName: function (name) {
            _name = name;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this too. It is still printing empty string.

Comment: add default value to name and try again.If you will get **name** then check your set part

Comment: Yea! If i initialize to name it is printing name! Its getting updated in my netController but in my page1Controller it is printing name only.

Comment: then check your setName() part. also you type console.log(NameService.netName) which must be console.log(NameService.getName());

Answer (score 0):

because when you call to print that variable, it's not defined yet. **$http** return promise and it needs some **time** interval.Have you tried to set interval inside **page1Controller**? like

```
App.controller('page1Controller', ['$scope', '$http','NameService', '$timeout' function($scope, $http,NameService, $timeout)
{
    $timeout(function(){
      console.log(NameService.name)
    },2000);
...
```

**Edited**

Then try something like this

```
gisApp.service('NameService', function(){
  return {
   Name: '',
   getName: function(){
     return this.Name;
   },
   setName: function(name){
     this.Name = name;
   }
});
```

because the syntax you use, you have to create a instance of that service using "**new**" to use it as a class.

Comment: I have tried ur suggestion! Still a empty string is being returned!

Comment: I didn't see.You use "setName" function.You don't have "netName" field.and you Don't have "name" field.You have "Name".no lowercase, with uppercase

Comment: I have made changes to my code! Still giving the same error.